# jquery horizontal ul/navbar slider

Tags: jquery, slider, uinavigationbar, navbar

I am working on a regular homepage that has an horizontal navigation bar (twitter bootstrap style).

The problem: based on an input when you enter the site, the page will display a mix of buttons in the navigation bar. It might display 4 buttons, or 20 buttons, depending on that input.

When there are too many buttons(a simple if buttons > x) I want to apply an horizontal slider that will animate/slide by one button when the user clicks on a prev/next button.

So far I have tried bxSlider (www.bxslider.com) and hoverscroll. Hoverscroll was ok, but I needed something click based rather than mouseover. BxSlider only slides by a fixed size on each click, and I want something that slides to an element, rather than pixels.

Thanks.

```
<div id="divone">
  <div id="divtwo">
    <ul id="my-list">
      <li>Link<li>
      <li>Link<li>
      <li>Link<li>
      <li>Link<li>
      <li>Link<li>
       etc.
    <ul>
  </div>
</div>



            #divone
            {
                width: 678px;
                height: 51px;
                position: relative;
            }

            #divtwo
            {
                width: 678px;
                height: 51px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #my-list
            {
                width: 6000px;
            }
```

That's the structure, possibly with another 'overflow:hidden' div parent so I can make a scrollable/sliding area.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post your existing html/css/jquery so we know what to write. I can write you a how-to solution, but, without your code, that's pretty much all I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specs, you stated that if you have a certain number of buttons, say "more than x buttons", you want the slider to appear. As such, you want to create a navigation bar that will look normal whether or not there is a slider. Unfortunately, I cannot help you with this aspect of the problem unless I can see your CSS; I will only be able to help you with the jQuery.

For starters, you will have to write out your conditional:

```
if ($("button").length > x) { ...show slider...}
```

Now before we continue, I would like to point out the obvious fact that there are a lot of different ways to go about making a slider. Without being able to see your code (I know I probably sound like a broken record at this point, but you're still new to Stack Overflow, so this is me teaching you), the most compatible solution that I can think of would be to create the navigation bar and leave enough space on the left and right sides for the slider buttons (we will manipulate the `visibility` property to show/hide them, not the `display` property - this will also keep the navigation bar from jumping on load in slower browsers).

To implement this, we will need to start with two elements (only selectors are shown) for the buttons:

```
var buttonLeft = $("#buttonLeft");
var buttonRight = $("#buttonRight");
```

Next, we will want to add the following lines to be run if our conditional was true:

```
buttonLeft.css("visibility", "visible")
          .on("click.sliderLeft", function() {...show more on the left...};
buttonRight.css("visibility", "visible")
           .on("click.sliderRight", function() {...show more on the right...};
```

Now before we begin to write the slide functions, it is important that you remember that when you want the slider to *show more elements from the left*, you actually want the element that is sliding to *move to the right*.

This is also another part of the script that could be implemented dozens of ways. The implementation that you choose will be based largely on your HTML and CSS. For this how-to, I will simply assume that you are going to be using a sliding element with `position: relative` and with some wrapper div that has `overflow: hidden`.

```
var navBar = $("#navBar"); // sliding element
```

The next step is to determine what you want to use for your slide effect. For sake of ease (and because you are using bootstrap - thus, you are more likely to have all buttons be the same size, anyway) I am going to assume all of your navigation buttons are the same size:

```
var navButtonWidth = $(".navButtons").width();
```

I am also going to assume, for sake of ease, that you have both the left and right margins of your buttons set to `5px`. I will further assume that each animation is going to take 1000 milliseconds. As such, you will want to add the following lines to your click handlers to serve as your slide effects:

```
var slideAmount = navButtonWidth + 10; //button width plus margin left plus margin right

//left button
...
var slideLeftStr = "+=" + slideAmount + "px";
navBar.animate({ left: slideStr }, 1000);
...

//right button
...
var slideRightStr = "-=" + slideAmount + "px";
navBar.animate({ left: slideStr }, 1000);
...
```

That's pretty much it. You will have to tailor it, customize it, add some conditionals for disabling the slide effect when the bar is at the end, add some work-arounds to prevent issues with double-clicking, etc., but this should give you a basic starting point for making your own dynamic slide effect.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! :)

**UPDATE:**

To answer your question about using the buttons to slide to a particular button, the answer is "yes, you can do that", but what you would really want to do is to slide to the start position of the next or previous button (respectively). I can tell you that this would likely look horrible, but here is the code anyway:

```
...
//put this function outside of the click handlers
var slideTo = function (destButton) {
    //destButton is the button you are sliding to
    return destButton.offset().left + "px";   
}     

//put this in both click handlers
...
var destinationButton = ....get the previous or next button based on which handler you're in
navBar.animate({ left: slideTo(destinationButton) }, 1000);
...
```

The option that I would suggest, however, is to write a click handler that has the navigation bar slide slowly as long as the user is still holding the mousedown over the button.

Comment: Because I'm dealing with a navigation bar, the buttons have their width according to their content. Thus, I am not sure how suited this pixel based option is. Is there something like "slide to the li:eq(x)" ?

Comment: The idea was to give a simple example in which you slide by a set amount.  You can also have the buttons slide continually while you hold the mouse down on the button